# SQL Server date format handling

Tags: sql-server, delphi, datetime

I am running the SAME Delphi 2007 code on two different Windows 7 machines and accessing the SAME SQL server database on a remote server. On one machine a date in the database is read in the format 2013-01-25 00:00:00.000 which causes the application to crash when it tries to convert this date to a DateTime. On the other machine a date is read in the format 1/25/2013 which is correctly converted to a DateTime without any issues.  What is causing this difference?  (I verified that the Control Panel 'Region and Language' settings on the two machines are identical). The dates in the database are stored as datetime2.

Comment: Don't know anything about Delphi, but the 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' that you are having a problem with is the standard return format for dates in sql server and your code should probably be fixed to handle it.  Also, could you post the code where you are pulling the information from the database?

Comment: Yes I am aware of the Cast and Convert functions however I would have to implement this everywhere a date is converted to a DateTime, which would be a HUGE effort.  I am wondering if there is a way to do this by running a query ONCE after the connection to the db is established. The code is straight forward: aQuery: 'Select curr_date from aTable'  myDate := aQuery.FieldByName('curr_date').asDateTime. If I check the value of aQuery.FieldByName('curr_date').ASSTRING just before the 'myDate' line is executed, on one machine it is 1/25/2013 and the other is 2013-01-25 00:00:00.000

Comment: what datatype is curr_date in the database?

Comment: datatype is datetime2

Comment: Check that `FieldByName('curr_date')` is not returned as `ftString` type (`TWideString`) when it actually needs to be a `TDateTimeField`. This could happen because `datetime2` is not correctly supported by the SQL Server OLEDB provider. so consider using `datetime` data type or switch to SQL Native Client provider (`SQLNCLI11`) or return the field as `CAST (curr_date AS DATETIME)`.

Answer (score 2):

> On one machine a date in the database is read in the format 2013-01-25 00:00:00.000 which causes the application to crash when it tries to convert this date to a DateTime. On the other machine a date is read in the format 1/25/2013 which is correctly converted to a DateTime without any issues

I don't know anything about Delphi but on the SQL Server side:

Date is a `Date` and does not have a format. If your column is of `Date` datatype, you shouldn't get any errors when converting to `DateTime`.

I suspect you may be storing date in a string type field in which case it would be best to use culture in-specific [ISO or ISO8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) before converting to `DateTime`.

Comment: All dates are type datetime2

Comment: No, I am simply running the statement myDate := aQuery.FieldByName('curr_date').asDateTime and the application crashes on this line on some machines but not others.

Comment: I think it is something in Delphi which I don't know about. I have added `[Delphi]` tag so that someone might pick it for you.